# Redirect to provider website after custom page SSO authentication

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to build a simple POC website.

Basically, user will use AzureB2C and Facebook as auth provider.  Once authenticated, I want to simply have a button that the user can click that would take them to facebook.com, authenticated.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you have any control over that. Just because someone "logged in with Facebook" doesn't mean they'll be auto-logged-in when visiting Facebook.com (I've used the azure portal too many times to know that's true). What are you after?

Comment: So, ultimately what we are after is this.

I setup a custom website (test.com), using SSO with a client (client.com).

The client also has SSO setup with another company (othercompany.com).

When they login to our custom site, using SSO, I want to put a button basically that will allow them to "Click Here" to get redirected to othercompany.com (that they've established SSO with).  I just don't think it will work?